# How to mix pairs of rows without JOIN (in a temporary table)?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a `TEMPORARY` table containing pairs of key/value as

```
id   col1      col2        type         pair
1    key1      key2        key          1
2    value1    value2      value        1
3    key3      key4        key          2
4    value3    value4      value        2
5    key5      key6        key          3
6    value5    value6      value        3
```

I want to mix the key/values as

```
pair    key_col1     key_col2      value_col1      value_col2
1       key1         key2          value1          value2
2       key3         key4          value3          value4
3       key5         key6          value5          value6
```

Since, it is a temporary table, I cannot use `JOIN`. How can I `SELECT` from this table to have pairs of key/value in each row?

Comment: Why can't you use `JOIN`?

Comment: @JeremySmyth `mysql` does not support `JOIN` to self on temporary tables. Temporary tables can be referenced only once in a query.

Comment: @All: really? Wow, that's lame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of data transformation is known as a `PIVOT` but unfortunately MySQL does not have a pivot function.  However, this can be replicated using both an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select pair,
  max(case when type = 'key' then col1 end) Key_col1,
  max(case when type = 'key' then col2 end) Key_col2,
  max(case when type = 'value' then col1 end) value_col1,
  max(case when type = 'value' then col2 end) value_col2
from temp
group by pair
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/834f6/5)

The result of the query is:

```
| PAIR | KEY_COL1 | KEY_COL2 | VALUE_COL1 | VALUE_COL2 |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |     key1 |     key2 |     value1 |     value2 |
|    2 |     key3 |     key4 |     value3 |     value4 |
|    3 |     key5 |     key6 |     value5 |     value6 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have the `pair` column to group on, you could use it with a `GROUP_CONCAT` to give you what you want, in conjunction with a hacky `IF(,,)` in a subquery. We're only referencing the temp table once, so it gets by MySQL's "Can't reopen table" error.

Try this:

```
SELECT pair, GROUP_CONCAT(key1) AS key_col1, GROUP_CONCAT(key2) AS key_col2,
             GROUP_CONCAT(val1) AS val_col1, GROUP_CONCAT(val2) AS val_col2
FROM (SELECT id,
             IF(type='key',   col1, NULL) key1,
             IF(type='key',   col2, NULL) key2,
             IF(type='value', col1, NULL) val1,
             IF(type='value', col2, NULL) val2,
             pair
      FROM temp) AS a
GROUP BY pair;
```

This will break quite deliciously if you've more than two rows per pair, but should behave well if you're in the middle of an edit and only have a key or a value for one pair.